# Turning off magic quotes in PHP doesnt seem to work

Tags: php

I am trying to turn magic quotes off in PHP but cannot get it to disable - I have set the below in /usr/local/lib/php.ini and restarted Apache but it has made no difference.

```
; Magic quotes

; Magic quotes for incoming GET/POST/Cookie data.
magic_quotes_gpc = Off

; Magic quotes for runtime-generated data, e.g. data from SQL, from exec(), etc.
magic_quotes_runtime = Off

; Use Sybase-style magic quotes (escape ' with '' instead of \').
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

phpinfo confirms these are all set to Off.

```
magic_quotes_gpc Off Off
magic_quotes_runtime Off Off
magic_quotes_sybase Off Off
```

I then tried adding

```
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
```

to htaccess but that gives a 500 Internal Server error - looking in error_log there is nothing added to tell me why this might be happening.

Server is running Centos 5.8 64 bit with CPanel/WHM and the front end is Wordpress with a custom PHP application in the background. PHP version is 5.3.18 and Loaded Configuration File is /usr/local/lib/php.ini

The reason I think it is not working is that the following message which is pulled from MySQL where it had mysql_real_escape_string, addslashes and htmlspecialchars applied to it before adding to the database.

The original message is:

```
This is a "how to" question. I don't think it is covered in the notes - sorry if I've missed it.
```

It gets added to MySQL as:

```
This is a &quot;how to&quot; question. I don\'t think it is covered in the notes - sorry if I\'ve missed it.
```

When it is then displayed on the screen it displays as:

```
This is a \\"how to\\" question. I don\\\'t think it is covered in the notes - sorry if I\\\'ve missed it.
```

And when stripslashes is then applied to this, it becomes:

```
This is a \&quot;how to\&quot; question. I don\'t think it is covered in the notes - sorry if I\'ve missed it.
```

What am I doing wrong or what else can I try?

Comment: I'm no expert in this field, but I suspect it could be **extremely** useful to also have in your question an example of why you think it's not working, ie, show us what PHP is doing that you want it not to do.

Comment: I would suggest creating a small test PHP file containing "<?php phpinfo();" first which will show you whether an ini file is being read, the path to that ini file, as well as the current values for the above settings.

Comment: I have edited my post with all the information requested, thanks for your comments

Comment: This seems like a programming question, and an oldschool one at that (I thought everyone handled this through robust frameworks these days), voting to move to Stackoverflow

Comment: I agree it should probably be on Stack now as it has become more about my PHP code itself than PHP admin which I originally thought it was

Comment: Not sure what the downvote is for but, regardless, anyone got any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

`\&quot;` is not the result of magic quotes or addslashes().

Plus, I can't think of a standard PHP quoting function that would replace double quotes with `\&quot;` and escapes single quotes with a slash. You've got something deeper wrong with your code.

Comment: htmlspecialchars changes " to &quot;

Comment: Yes, but it does not escape single quotes with a backslash. My point is there is not one function that does both.

Comment: I have added more info to the original message to show the output I see at each stage